# Как сделать всплывающие сообщения с запуском из PHP на CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать всплывающее сообщения *(к примеру, об ошибке)* с активацией анимации из php *(Например, я хочу создать файл, а такой файл уже есть, и я получаю сообщение об ошибке).*
В гугле нашел [такие вот сообщения](https://www.idg.net.ua/blog/wp-content/uploads/vsplyvajushhie-uvedomlenija-css.html), но до меня никак не дойдет, как сделать активацию не при клике на кнопку, а **прямиком из PHP кода.**

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью twitter bootstrap, например.
PHP тут не играет никакой роли. Разве что выводит HTML.

```js
$(".alert").alert()
```

```html
<htmL>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```